How to have the Prometheus exporter export labels/tags
I am creating the meter like this:
var meter = fact.Create( MeterName, 
  null, 
  new KeyValuePair<string, object?>[] { 
    new( "id", index.Id ), 
    new( "name", index.Name ) } );

I expected id and name to be rendered as labels/tags. But only otel scopes are rendered which I do not need (but could live with if that would be an addition).
How to have the exporter render the labels/tags? I found How can find or correctly export resource labels of OpenTelemetry metrics in Prometeus? but I don't have a config file like this as I am implementing a micro service exposing /metrics endpoint and there the labels are already missing, so a config file is not applicable.
The scraping is not done by a otel exporter but by some scraping configured through annotations in k8s yaml files

See if following helps.  Looks like you may need a yml file : https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/

@jdweng I can add tags while scraping but those tags are values from the app itself

You need to enable.  The link says "The resource attributes to metrics label conversion is disabled by default. Please update the otel config to following to see the resource attribute is prom UI."

On the prometheus side they are enabled. But question is: how to enable them in the dotnet app? prometheus and the scraper cannot add metrics that rely on the thing beihg scraped, can it?

If they are already enabled why do you need to enable again.

Because with the Prometheus exporter from Open telemetry inside the application they get not rendered out. Just an otel scope label. This was never a question about infrastructure but how to have custom labels rendered through otel Prometheus exporter. Calling /metrics do not show the labels therefore nothing somewhere else could show them

Is the issue the config?  You said "but I don't have a config file like this"

Because of the nature of building a dotnet app providing metrics through an HTTP endpoint I do not have a config file. I do have an endpoint /metrics where metrics are published and are ready to be collected. Except that Open Telemetry does not render any custom labels

Edited my question to clarify

Read following : https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/

I think there's some confusion here, @Sascha wants the metrics endpoint of their .NET app to list the tags found in the Tags list passed to a Meter in .NET.
This is a .NET specific issue and actually nothing to do with Prometheus' config. The metrics endpoint within .NET isn't providing the tags as labels.  Given a metric called "hats", they want hats{id="123",name="Test"} to appear from the .NET Metrics enpoint.

This is probably something in: OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.HttpListener or OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore I'm also experiencing the issue so I'll continue digging.

This documentation says it should be supported. There's also confirmation from a maintainer
Perhaps its a versioning thing. I will experiment and answer if i can.

This Test
Doesn't test, Meter tags but does test individual metric tags which are set when you provide a value. I'm going to create a minimum reproduction project and Open an issue I guess.

This is now raised as a bug on opentelemtry-dotnet you can read the bug report here

I believe this is potentially caused by a bug in OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.HttpListener
I have opened a bug for this here. Which is based on this conversation in their discussion boards.
But for now, there is a work around.
You can get those tags to show up, if you pass them to your actual Add/Set/Record operations.
So for example:
var tags = new KeyValuePair<string, object?>[] { 
    new( "id", index.Id ), 
    new( "name", index.Name ) } );

// Don't pass the tags in here,
var meter = fact.Create(MeterName);
var counter = meter.CreateCounter<int>("counter");

// Instead pass the tags in via Add/Set/Record.
counter.Add(1, tags);

It does present a few challenges as you'll have to keep the tags in scope for whenever you need them, but it is good enough for now. I'll be monitoring my question on GitHub for an answer.
EDIT: Open Telemetry recently published a fix which has this bug resolved. You can see this version here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/releases/tag/coreunstable-1.10.0-beta.1
It was released: 2024-11-12
If you update, to that unstable version, your bug should be resolved.
